# Java: For loop not displaying all output numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, output

I am trying to create a For loop program where a user enters the starting number and the ending number, and then presses a button to show the values. Example:

[image: Example of the program I am trying to create]

However, when I run my program and press the button, it only displays the ending number, like so:

[image: What my program looks like when I press the button]

Here is what my code looks like so far: I haven't been able to find any logical errors so far.

```
 private void valuesButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
        int starting;
        starting = Integer.parseInt(startingInput.getText());
        
        int ending;
        ending = Integer.parseInt(endingInput.getText());
        
        for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++){
            outputField.setText(i + "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're just resetting the `outputField` to **every** value in the loop so you just end up with the last one.  You need to **concatenate** the numbers.  Have a look at `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

Comment: java.lang.StringBuilder ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is replacing the old content of `outputField`:

```
outputField.setText(i + "");
```

You should write it as follows:

```
outputField.setText(outputField.getText() + i + " ");
```

i.e. append `i + " "` to the old content of `outputField`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the step where you concatenate all numbers:

```
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++){
      text.append(i).append(" ");
    }
    outputField.setText(text.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `setText` is *overwriting* the string in the output field; the final call is when `i == ending`, so the ending number is what you see. What you want is to *concatenate* the new number to the previous output string.

One solution may be to store the output as a String, append each number in the loop, and then set the text to the output string.

```java
String output = "";

for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++) {
    output += i + " ";
}

outputField.setText(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
    for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++){
        outputField.setText(i + "");
    }
```

sets the output to one number, then the next, then the next... and happens so fast all you see is the last.

Try this: it accumulates the output so far, and uses that to display.

```
    String s = "";
    for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++) {
        s = s + i + " ";
        outputField.setText(s);
    }
```

This is still outputting the intermediate results, so is a little wasteful and still happening too fast to see.   But it's closest to your original, so I left it like that.   You could move the setText call to after the end of the loop to only output the final result.

Other answers mention StringBuilder, but I did not; I hesitate to introduce too many new concepts at once.  StringBuilder has a role in cases where performance matters, but that does not apply here, and I think 'obviousness' wins for introductory exercises.